# Elegant way to edit a database through a browser?

Tags: mysql, web-applications, client-side, server-side

My project involves a grid of text/number data that I'm currently storing in a MySQL database. The user can enter a new row of data at the bottom of the grid (e.g. a new entry into the database), or can delete rows. ...think of it as a very primitive browser-based Excel.

Right now I'm using PHP/MySQL and some javascript, but it's turning into a bit of a mess. (Minor features like adding a new column/entry to the grid are overly complex.) I also don't like having to use PHP forms ($_POST, etc) with irritating redirects and such.

Is there a better language or framework to use? I think the basic issue is that I want to rather seamlessly combine client-side and server-side coding.

Comment: I am not sure how there would be a definite answer to this question. Lots of languages/frameworks out there can do this. Which server-side language do you prefer?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with php, a colleague of mine created this: [OpenJS DataGrid](http://square-bracket.com/openjs)

A few (of many) youtube tutorials:

1. [OpenJS Grid v2 - Awesome jQuery Data Table](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFbYZbz03w0&list=UUDn9DtRM2xEFrhbzL5e0BeQ&index=4&feature=plcp)
2. [OpenJS Grid 1.4 (Adding and Deleting)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sTSSmeQdDYo&feature=relmfu)
3. [OpenJS Grid - an Open Source JQuery Grid](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NHwWesxrqiU&feature=relmfu)

Answer (score 0):

Try DataTables.net, it's a Web 2.0 framework for tabluar data. You can tell it to use Ajax and do the server side however you want, e.g. with PHP and MySQL. Examples here:

- Basic: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/editable.html
- Additionaly try the editor extension: http://editor.datatables.net/